# Naming system of Judo techniques

Tags: judo, technique, terminology, japanese

Is there a system to the way judo techniques are named? Many techniques seem to share components of names (*harai, guruma, gaeshi* etc) - is there a standard uniform way these words should be interpreted as describing these techniques, or are they context dependent?

Answer (score 4):

The *Kodokan New Japanese-English Dictionary of Judo* has entries on most verbs used in technique names:

| Word | Definition | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| haneru | (**to spring/jump**) A situation in which the powerful effect of a hane goshi or uchimata sends your opponent's body high into the air. | *hane-goshi, hane-makikomi* |
| harau | (**to sweep**) To throw by acting on your opponent's feet, legs, or trunk with a sweeping type motion. | *harai-goshi, harai-tsumikomi-ashi, de-ashi-barai, okuri-ashi-barai* |
| hikikomu | (**to pull into**) To pull your opponent into a particular position, particularly as a way of moving into mat-work (newaza). | *hikikomi-gaeshi* |
| kaesu | (**to reverse; to counterattack**) To stop an opponent's attack and then execute an attack or counterattack of your own. | *osoto-gaeshi, ouchi-gaeshi, kouchi-gaeshi, tsubame-gaeshi, hane-goshi-gaeshi, harai-goshi-gaeshi, uchi-mata-gaeshi kibisu-gaeshi, obi-tori-gaeshi, sumi-gaeshi, hikikomi-gaeshi, tawara-gaeshi* |
| karu | (**to reap**) To sweep your opponent's feet, legs, or hips out from under him using reaping motions of your feet and legs. | *osoto-gari, kosoto-gari, ouchi-gari, kouchi-gari* |
| katameru | (**to pin; to hold down**) To use a hold-down technique to pin your opponent's body, or a portion of his body, in such a way that his freedom of movement is controlled and he is unable to move. | *katame-waza* |
| makikomu | (**to wrap**) To throw in such a way that part of your opponent's body wraps around yours as part of your technique, a common element in many sacrifice techniques. | *osoto-makikomi, hane-makikomi, harai-makikomi, uchi-mata-makikomi, kouchi-makikomi, soto-makikomi, uchi-makikomi* |
| nageru | (**to throw**) In judo the use of the hands, hips, feet and legs in a coordinated fashion and in accordance with the principles of physics in such a way that you cause your opponent to fall or roll forward, backward, or to the side. | *nage-waza, seoi-nage, sukui-nage, ura-nage, tomoe-nage* |
| osaekomu | (**to hold down**) To hold your opponent down on the mat from above so as to render him unable to move. | *osaekomi-waza* |
| osaeru | (**to hold down**) To face your opponent and hold him down on the mat so as to render him unable to move. |  |
| sasaeru | (**to support; to block**) To use your feet, legs, or hips to block an opponent's attempts to move his body or a part of his body freely. | *sasae-tsurikomi-ashi* |
| seou | (**to load something onto your back**) To load your opponent onto your hips and/or back. | *ipponzeoi-nage, seoi-nage, seoi-otoshi* |
| shimeru | (**to strangle; to choke**) To apply pressure to your opponent's neck using your hands, arms, legs, or by manipulating his collar or lapel. | *shime-waza, hadaka-jime* |
| taosu | (**to throw down**) To throw down or otherwise defeat your opponent. | *kuchiki-taoshi* |
| tsurikomu | (**to lift and pull**) To use lifting and pulling movements of the sleeve hand (hikite) and collar hand (tsurite) in order to "float" your opponent forward. | *tsurikomi-goshi, sode-tsurikomi-goshi, sasae-tsurikomi-ashi, harai-tsurikomi-ashi* |
| ukasu | (**to float something upwards**) To lift and pull your own body or your opponent's body in a way that it becomes nearly weightless for an instant. | *uki-goshi, uki-otoshi, uki-waza, uki-gatame* |

Note that technique names usually employ the continuative tense of the verb (ending *-i / -e*), but the infinitive (generally in *-u*) is listed here.

Answer (score 1):

In judo the application of the techniques is done with a preponderance of one limb. That is clear. The classification of the techniques accounts for that. So there are groups of main activity of applying *fulcrums* like:

- Te waza, Ashi waza, koshi waza

or  after the *direction* of falls:

- sutemi waza, uki waza, makikomi waza